# GeoJson fill color, stroke color not willing to load in browser

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

I am not good in explaining this, but I will do my best.

I am using GeoJson to load layers in google maps. for so far everything works. But when I tried to add colors it didn't show them.

I first add the color in this link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MissAudi/Relipop/master/GeoJson%20file
if I load this GeoJson file in geojson.io it shows all of the colors I added.
But when I add this GeoJson file to my website it doesn show the color anymore.

The GeoJson file is loaded in map.geojson in the code.
This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <h1>My First Google Map</h1>
  <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:1000px;"></div>

  <script>
    function myMap() {
      var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.6763643, -100.2707594),
        zoom: 5
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

      var promise = $.getJSON('map.geojson');
      promise.then(function(data) {
        cachedGeoJson = data;
        map.data.addGeoJson(cachedGeoJson);
      })


    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD9KDXscBtm5sLLTN2Rg9eNFJcLj3H8MAU&callback=myMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/geojson-styling-information help?

Comment: That shuts down the whole file, I already tried that one. Then it shows nothing anymore. not even the states.

Comment: nevermind ... I'm a derp

Comment: That doesn matter thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: have you tried the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138463/setting-different-fill-colors-for-geojson-objects-in-google-maps-api

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcjw0psa/1/) works - but it's probably showing what you've done wrong rather than the way to do it :p

Comment: Thanks that really helped!!! :)

Comment: and yes it indeed shows what I did wrong

Comment: hmm, I thought perhaps you needed to use `fillColor` and `strokeColor` instead of `fill` and `stroke` properties, but could not make that work myself!

Comment: that works in geojson.io , I suppose not in normal files or something